# Is there a way to delay deletion of a Firebase user and their associated data?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-functions

I'm creating a Flutter app that is using Firebase as a backend for authentication with firestore as a database and storage for larger files to store some user data. I want to allow users to delete their account and all associated data, but I don't want this to be done immediately so that users can recover their account if they decide to come back within 15 days or so.

I originally thought I could do this with a Firebase Function that I could call from my app, which is shown here:

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';

const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();

const fifteenDays = 1296000000;

export const helloWorld = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
    setTimeout(async () => {
        try {
            await admin.auth().deleteUser(data.id);
            console.log(`Deleted User: ${data.id}`);
            await admin.firestore().collection("users").document(data.id).delete();
            console.log(`Deleted User Firestore: ${data.id}`);
            await admin.storage().bucket().deleteFiles({
                    prefix: `userPhotos/${data.id}/`,
                    force: true,
                },
                function(err: any) {
                    if (err) {
                        console.log(err);
                    }
                    else {
                        console.log(`All the Firebase Storage files in users/${data.id}/ have been deleted`);
                    }
                }
            );
        }
        catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    }, fifteenDays);

});
```

But after reading [Firebase Functions Tips & tricks](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/tips) to find a method of cancelling the timeout, I saw that code run after function termination can't access the CPU so this code won't even work.

Does anyone have any suggestions of a method in achieving what I need with the ability to cancel the scheduled deletion? Any **free** solution would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could always create a collection of, for example, "Users_to_delete", and in the documents insert the user ID and the date to delete it.

For example

```
Users_to_delete

|----Document ID

|-------- UserID

|-------- Date_to_delete
```

Then run a function every day/hour in cloud functions that checks the collection filtering with the current day and deleting every user that is there.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! Unfortunately Firebase Function scheduling is not [free](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/schedule-functions). Do you know of any alternatives I could use?

Comment: @ChristopherMoore it seems that you can have 3 free jobs. "Though billing is required, you can expect the overall cost to be manageable, as each Cloud Scheduler job costs $0.10 (USD) per month, and there is an allowance of three free jobs per Google account. Use the Blaze pricing calculator to generate a cost estimate based on your projected usage."

Comment: Do you know if you still have to be on the Blaze plan to use those 3 free jobs? It seems you have to be on the Blaze plan still to even use those 3 jobs. I'll try it out if you don't know.

Comment: @ChristopherMoore Yes, you must be on the blaze plan. If you want a free one and you do have a server running, you could run a node job and schedule there to call directly the function on your scheduled times.